# Tiling rectangle with trominoes — an invariant

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling

There are two types of [trominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino), straight shapes and L-shaped. Suppose a rectangle $R$ admits at least one tiling using trominoes, with an even number of L-trominoes.

**EDIT:** we do not admit ALL orientations, but only those which are constructed by starting in a box, and next box is placed to the left, or below previous box.
Hence, only 2 out of the 4 possible orientations of the L-tromino is allowed. Hence, these are the four trominoes that we are allowed to use:

$$\begin{align}\newcommand{\x}{\large\blacksquare}\newcommand{\o}{\large\phantom{\square}}
&\o\o\o\o\o\o\o\o\o\o\x\\[-5pt]
&\x\x\o\o\o\o\x\o\o\o\x\\[-5pt]
&\x\o\o\o\o\x\x\o\o\o\x\o\o\o\x\x\x
\end{align}$$

*Prove that every tiling of $R$ must use an even number of L-trominoes.*

This smells a lot like a classical tiling problem, but unlike the classical cases (dominoes and missing corners), the situation is not to show that a tiling is impossible…. Some nice invariant is perhaps what I am looking for.

I actually know how to prove the above statement, but it requires a lot more machinery than I would like. Moreover, I am interested in a more general question, (regarding representation theory and cylindrical Schur functions, and the proof I know does not generalize to this situation), but I hope that a good proof of the above problem generalizes.

For the interested: The general setting supposes that the rectangle is a torus, and that we use $k$-ribbons, where $k$ is odd. We then want to show that the number of $k$-ribbons which occupies an even number of rows, occur an even number of times. Hence, a proof not relying on the fact that $R$ has boundaries, or heavily uses the fact that each shape has three squares, is of extra interest.

**EDIT2:** 2022-12-09 So, I am in the process of writing up a proof of this (and some other stuff).

Comment: Do you know whether the statement can be strengthened to: every tiling of $R$ must use an even number of "north/east plus south/west L-trominoes" and an even number of "north/west plus south/east L-trominoes"? Or any other statement about the orientation of the L-trominoes?

Comment: Isn't the result false on a torus? Take rows $(112, 133, 232)$ and numbers indicate where the tiles are.

Comment: hm really? http://www.matematika-shkolnikam.ru/43.jpg

Comment: Fedor's theorem is stronger than mine.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ah, sh*t, i need one extra condition - I want to show that no rectangle admits both odd and even number of L-trominoes then (the special case I am interested in seem to only admit even number of L-trominoes)...

Comment: For torus, you can also use the rectangle tiling $(111,223,233)$ which has two L's.

Comment: Also, since $3$ is prime, the sizes are $m\times n$ where one is divisible by $3$, so you always have a tiling with no L's which is even.

Comment: @VilleSalo Well, I need to add some extra conditions for the torus - the case I have in mind does not simply glue the edges together, but there is also a shift...
But it is nice to know that the shift might be relevant.

Comment: I guess the tag should be [tag:tiling], not [tag:tilting].

Comment: To make the edit clearer: the permitted orientations are "2 by 2 block missing northwest/top-left square" and "2 by 2 block missing southeast/bottom-right square", right?

Comment: @user44191 yes, that is correct.

Comment: A more general theory is due to Igor Pak, https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2000-352-12/S0002-9947-00-02666-0/S0002-9947-00-02666-0.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley yes, I am aware of that, but his machinery does not generalize to the torus setting, so I was hoping for an alternative approach...

Comment: Have you looked at diagonals skewed to your pieces?  (Two of the pieces occupy 2 squares of a certain diagonal direction, while the others occupy only one;alternatively,two pieces lie within two diagonals, whereas the others cross three diagonals.) Gerhard "Hoping For A New Slant" Paseman, 2020.01.22.

Comment: It may be worth noting that any invariant that is linear in the "filled" squares (more formally, that can be extended to a linear function in the "filled" squares) will not work. A 2 by 6 rectangle can be filled by 3 non-overlapping same-orientation L-trominos with 3 squares blank; those squares can then be filled by 2 I-trominoes minus another one.

Comment: A possible simplification: is there some invariant (besides "total number of squares modulo 3") on Young tableaux under 1) lengthening any row by 3, 2) turning a row into 4 rows (of the same length), and 3) lengthening any 3 rows of the same length by 1? This should correspond to invariants under addition of arbitrary I-trominos.

Comment: @user44191 well, the invariant is the sign of a Sn-character... as far as I know, this is quite complicated...

Comment: Do you have any examples of tilings with different numbers of the two orientations of the L-trominos?

Comment: @user44191 No, and for rectangles, they have to be equal in numbers..

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: your last comment on the two L-shapes having equal multiplicity, does it follow from the results in Pak's paper? From just a cursory reading I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I believe that it does, but I do not remember exactly from where

Comment: @user44191 - adding to your comment about linear invariants - it's even worse. A disjoint union of a 1x3 horizontal rectangle, a horizontal cylinder of circumference 9 and length 2, and a 3x3 torus is indistinguishable from the 10x3 rectangle in terms of: area=30, left/right border length=10, top/bottom length=3, number of corners=4, absence of concavity along the border! Yet the disjoint figure can be tiled with unequal numbers of the 2 L-shapes, due to the torus. I can't think of any equation (linear or not) that could capture the connectedness and thus distinguish between the 2 cases.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Feel free to edit the question, I did not manage to get that command to work (there is some issue with the -5pt command, i think.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, the link from your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350931/tiling-rectangle-with-trominoes-an-invariant#comment879361_350931) now goes to a generic [landing page](https://nauka.club/matematika), and the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.matematika-shkolnikam.ru/43.jpg) doesn't remember the image.  Do you know where to find it now?

Comment: Prior comment clarified: any invariant must separate the 2 cases $\quad\newcommand{\x}{\large\blacksquare}\begin{align}\x\\[-5pt]\x\\[-5pt]\x\end{align}\,\cup\,$ $\big\uparrow\begin{align}&\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\end{align}\big\uparrow\,\cup\,$ $\big\uparrow\begin{align}&\,\,\longrightarrow\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\,\,\longrightarrow\end{align}\big\uparrow\quad$ and $\quad\begin{align}&\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\\[-5pt]&\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x \end{align},\quad$ since the 1st can be tiled with different numbers of L-shapes.

Comment: @LSpice I think, it was 5*9 partitioned onto corners. Like this:112233455/162773445
6688799AA/BCC8DE9AF/BBCDDEEFF

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I know it's a three year old thread but, yes, "number of northwest L's" - "number of southeast L's" is Pak's invariant $f_1$. See the discussion after Theorem 1.4,

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Are you still interested in this? I thought about it a bit this morning, and I think the following are probably right: (1) Given a ribbon tiling of the torus, it is always possible to cut it open to make a make a ribbon tiling of a cylinder (see https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/cylindricSchur.htm ). (2) It should be pretty straightforward to work out a version of Pak's theory for cylindrical ribbon tableaux. However, (3) the same size torus can give rise to many different cylindrical shapes, and it isn't clear how to relate them.

Comment: Also (4) going from "ribbon tiling" to "ribbon tableaux" (the analogue of Pak's Lemma 3.4) isn't so easy in the cylindrical case. In short, I put some thought into this, figured out a few things, but there is a lot which can go wrong and I'm not sure it is worth writing down the details.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, so I am still interested in this, and I hope to have a preprint out soon (within 3-4 weeks). It has some applications to cylindric Schur functions as you noted which was one of the inspirations of this problem.
So, one can find an invariant that works, but it is not the most natural as it requires some non-commutative thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start on a proof. I ask Per to finish it up.

The constraints allow me to color diagonals of the array in three distinct colors. (I choose a periodic pattern of red, green, and blue.) Two of Per's pieces remove one of each color, while the other two (because of how they orient and how I choose my diagonal coloring) cover two of one color and one of another.  This imbalance should allow a parity argument for the L shaped pieces.  Note this doesn't work if any of the other orientations are allowed.

Gerhard "Only Giving Half A Proof" Paseman, 2020.01.22.

Comment: I'm still seeing issues with this because I think of a strip of nested L pieces of one orientation spanning part of the torus. Perhaps Per has more of the picture and can use the idea of solving with this invariant anyway.  Gerhard "Maybe He Can Force Herringbone" Paseman, 2020.01.22.

Comment: Indeed, if I use a three by three torus, I can tile it with three L shapes of the same orientation.  Hopefully he can rule that and similar out.  Gerhard "If Not One, The Other" Paseman, 2020.01.22.

Comment: Well, forget about the torus for the moment, but I am not convinced  about the diagonal argument. You can have one type of L-piece, three copies with the 3 possible colorings. This is indistinguishable from three of the straight shapes.

Comment: That is true,  but if two L's are oriented in opposite fashion, there is only one configuration (up to color) that maintains equicolor balance.  Gerhard "If You Look For Balance..." Paseman, 2020.01.22.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman. Your argument is not completely fruitless. With simple vector arithmetic it can be used to show that the numbers of the two L-shapes are congruent (mod 3). But nothing more than that.